# Как написать скрипт, чтобы он удалял все пустые ячейки и строки с заданного диапазона в гугл таблице?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G5zt_tl-5fpYxmRCwSrI8ecvkB05hXt99DJyH4vH6Vw/edit#gid=554280418
Делал макрос, но если добавить или убавить строки нужно его переписывать. Хотелось бы сделать это все скриптом, чтобы указывать диапазон, а не переписывать весь макрос.
Между 2 табличками(в листе было) надо скриптом удалить пустые строки(чтобы получилось как в листе стало).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Скрипт удаляет все пустые строки на листе:
function deleteEmptyRows(){ 
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
      var targetData = new Array();
      for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){
        if(data[n].join().replace(/,/g,'')!=''){ targetData.push(data[n])};
        Logger.log(data[n].join().replace(/,/g,''))
      }
      sh.getDataRange().clear();
      sh.getRange(1,1,targetData.length,targetData[0].length).setValues(targetData);
    }
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).